# Angular Update form populates input fields but still returns error in console?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create an update form in Angular. I have tried many things but then again im not very familiar with Angular to begin with. This seems pretty straight forward though, I am getting the data using the `ngOnInit()` method (which is returning the correct data). The user data is displayed in the input fields but then the error comes up.

This is the error that I get in the console:

```
UpdateComponent.html:6 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (UpdateComponent.html:6)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11914)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11307)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:11490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11313)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:11511)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:11308)
    at callViewAction (core.js:11548)
```

My `update.component.html` file:

```
<div>
<h2 class="page-header">Edit your Profile</h2>
<form (ngSubmit)="onUpdateSubmit(user)" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="user.age" name="age" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age" min="0" max="200">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="favoriteFood">What is your Favorite Food?</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.favoriteFood" name="favoriteFood" class="form-control" id="favoriteFood" placeholder="Favorite Food">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</div><div>
<h2 class="page-header">Edit your Profile</h2>
<form (ngSubmit)="onUpdateSubmit(user)" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="user.age" name="age" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Age" min="0" max="200">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="favoriteFood">What is your Favorite Food?</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.favoriteFood" name="favoriteFood" class="form-control" id="favoriteFood" placeholder="Favorite Food">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

My `update.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { ValidateService } from '../../services/validate.service';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update',
  templateUrl: './update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update.component.css']
})
export class UpdateComponent implements OnInit {
  user: Object;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private validateService: ValidateService,
    private router: Router,
    private _flashMessagesService: FlashMessagesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.user = profile.user;
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }

  onUpdateSubmit(user) {
    console.log("Component", user)
    // Required Fields
    if(!this.validateService.validateSignup(user)) {
      this._flashMessagesService.show("Please fill in all fields", {cssClass: "alert-danger", timeout: 3000});
      return false;
    }

    // Validate Email
    if(!this.validateService.validateEmail(user.email)) {
      this._flashMessagesService.show("Please use valid email", {cssClass: "alert-danger", timeout: 3000});
      return false;
    }

    // Update user
    this.authService.updateUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      if(data.success) {
        this._flashMessagesService.show("Update Success!", {cssClass: "alert-success", timeout: 3000});
        this.router.navigate(["/profile"]);
      } else {
        this._flashMessagesService.show("Something went wrong", {cssClass: "alert-danger", timeout: 3000});
        this.router.navigate(["/update"]);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is no `firstName` returned in user data. Maybe it is undefined. To avoid the issue.

You'd better: 1. Check the user data in `ngOnInit()` if it is returned. 2. Initial user data. e,g: `user = { firstName: '' };` 3. Check whether there is a delay when get user data from service

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, so I checked the data and it is correct: 
 {_id: "5af80141f4a59c46e03f4471", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 24, favoriteFood: "Pizza", …}

What did you mean about the 2nd part, initial user data? should I be setting firstName to an empty string?

Comment: Never mind, wow thank you I totally get it. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @paperboi, It is better to initial user object to avoid undefined issue. But about your question. I think this is because there is time detention when get the user data form `authService`.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a two way binding in your form , then why you need to pass the user on form submit. Try using as below

```
   <form (ngSubmit)="onUpdateSubmit()" novalidate>
    .
    .
    .
```

and use

```
  onUpdateSubmit() {
    console.log("Component", this.user);
    .
    .
    .
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is clear. Your user is populated by api call on `ngOnInit` which however, may return a response after the html is loaded. While loading, your DOM expect user to the available but its undefined in your case. There are few ways you can fix this. First , folloow the usual standard, define your user like below in your constructor.

```
constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private validateService: ValidateService,
    private router: Router,
    private _flashMessagesService: FlashMessagesService
  ) { 

   this.user = <Object>{};
}
```

Now your user is not undefined and even though `user.name` might be , it will be briefly and error will not be thrown. Second option is, update your `update.component.html`, load your DOM only when user is available or not undefined. To do this, add *ngIf in your first div

```
<div *ngIf="user">
<h2 class="page-header">Edit your Profile</h2>
<form (ngSubmit)="onUpdateSubmit(user)" novalidate>
........
.........
</form
</div>
```

Form the above, your form will not be loaded when user is undefined hence the need for user.name is avoided .

Comment: Oh nice, Thanks! I will write it this way

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no `firstName` defined in user data. This is because at the time of your page loads, your `user` object is not initialised. If there is no  object assigned to `this.user` in `ngOnInit` it will return an exception.
You can fix this in two ways.
One method is to initialize the `this.user` object at the beginning. It will return a blank form if there is no object is assigned to the user object in `ngOnInit` but it won't return an exception. You can do it by simply initializing the `user` object when defining the object or in the constructor.

when defining the object

```
user={}
```

or in constructor

```
this.user={}
```

Second method is, in case you want to display the form only if there are data you can use the `*ngIf` to display the form only when the there are data in the `user` object.

```
<div *ngIf="user">
<h2 class="page-header">Edit your Profile</h2>
<form (ngSubmit)="onUpdateSubmit(user)" novalidate>
........
.........
</form
</div>
```